# is there any way to display jupyter notebooks with django

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook, django-file-upload

I am really new on these things and i want to create a blog that i can publish my data notes and other articles. I want to learn if there is any way to display my jupyter notebooks or (.pdf, .docx, etc.) files directly on my website?

I am already appreciate for your advice and answers. Thanks.

Comment: It's quite easy if your notebooks are static. You can download them as HTML from the Jupyter "File" -> "Download as" menu.

Comment: Hey @stever. Thanks for your help. I think my question is not obvious enough. Firstly, i am sorry for that. Actually, I want to learn how can i use these static files dynamically if it is possible.

Comment: No sorries.  My comment was pretty flawed.  I'm shutting down for the evening but maybe look into nbconvert and/or iframes.